# divide the iframe with same page into 2 video and button and apply fillter to the button without effect video

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I want to divide the iframe that contains video and button 1.2.3.4.5 and with same page  , make it work to gather, and I want to divide the button alone to apply filler inversion (1) without effecting the video part.

divide the iframe that contains video and button and add  with same page fillter:invert(1)
[filter: invert() effect video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAm7L.png)

Comment: Now we know what you want, what is your programming related question? What goes wrong with your current code?

Comment: I have a site that contains iframe. I can't change the iframe color because they are not in the same domain, and I can't apply filler because it will effect the video, so I want to divide the iframe into 2 iframes that allow me to apply filler without effecting the video.

Comment: On a web page there's no way to access a cross-domain document of the iframe in a browser, you've to use a proxy server, or scrape the content on your server.

Comment: Codepen https://cdpn.io/pen/debug/OJwOOyv?authentication_hash=ZoMBaQGOgJVk